# IndexedDB: UnknownError: The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other error code. (error code 0)

Tags: firefox, indexeddb

I'm trying to migrate an IndexedDB database to a different instance of Firefox.

I can migrate it to a different site (or directory, for file URLs) just by copying `~/.mozilla/firefox/PROFILE/storage/default/file++++...` to the new name.

I can also migrate to a different profile in the same Firefox instance.

But if I create a new home directory (`export HOME=/tmp/test-home`) and copy into that, then Firefox refuses to open the database, giving the error:

> UnknownError: The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other error code. (error code 0))

(I actually want to migrate to a new machine, but testing with the same machine, user, and FF version narrows down the problem)

What tests does FF do to decide whether to allow opening the database? I see a binary `.metadata` file with a path in, and also a `.sqlite` file with it in the "database" table (which I tried updating manually).

I'm testing with Firefox 40.0.3.

---

Update: found this in the Javascript console:

```
Security Error: Content at file:///home/.../ may not load data from file:///cache.manifest.
Quota 'idb' is not a valid schema!: QuotaManager.cpp:4932 <unknown>
Quota Origin 'idb' failed to parse, handled tokens: : QuotaManager.cpp:4858 <unknown>
IndexedDB UnknownErr: ActorsParent.cpp:573
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata file gives the old origin. Firefox's QuotaManager loads the metadata file, reads the old origin, and tries to scan the 'idb' directory for the old origin. This directory doesn't exist and so it aborts. If the metadata file is deleted, Firefox will recreate it with the correct contents.

Also, make sure the target Firefox instance is at least as new as the source one. I also got this error with Firefox 37 trying to read a file from Firefox 40.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post, it was helpful. 
Let me explain what I'm doing, and I think it will help you to at least understand the problem. So far as I can tell the hidden file .metadata is not related to this problem.

I'm trying to move a sqlite database from FFOS 2.1 to FFOS 2.6. The application uses the indexDB and so far as the application is aware nothing has changed (applicaiton, code, applicaiton's database are unchanged). However Firefox changed the schema of the database that stores the application's database. This back-end storage database is agnostic to the application database.

Using sqlite3 and the .schema command I can explain the differences:

Older 2.1

```
CREATE TABLE database (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, origin TEXT NOT NULL, version INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, last_vacuum_time INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, last_analyze_time INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, last_vacuum_size INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0) WITHOUT ROWID;
CREATE TABLE index_data( index_id INTEGER NOT NULL, value BLOB NOT NULL, object_data_key BLOB NOT NULL, object_store_id INTEGER NOT NULL, value_locale BLOB, PRIMARY KEY (index_id, value, object_data_key), FOREIGN KEY (index_id) REFERENCES object_store_index(id) , FOREIGN KEY (object_store_id, object_data_key) REFERENCES object_data(object_store_id, key) ) WITHOUT ROWID;
CREATE INDEX index_data_value_locale_index ON index_data (index_id, value_locale, object_data_key, value) WHERE value_locale IS NOT NULL;
CREATE TABLE object_store( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, auto_increment INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, name TEXT NOT NULL, key_path TEXT);
CREATE TABLE unique_index_data( index_id INTEGER NOT NULL, value BLOB NOT NULL, object_store_id INTEGER NOT NULL, object_data_key BLOB NOT NULL, value_localeBLOB, PRIMARY KEY (index_id, value), FOREIGN KEY (index_id) REFERENCES object_store_index(id) , FOREIGN KEY (object_store_id, object_data_key) REFERENCES object_data(object_store_id, key) ) WITHOUT ROWID;
CREATE INDEX unique_index_data_value_locale_index ON unique_index_data (index_id, value_locale, object_data_key, value) WHERE value_locale IS NOT NULL;
CREATE TABLE file (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, refcount INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE TRIGGER file_update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON file FOR EACH ROW WHEN NEW.refcount = 0 BEGIN DELETE FROM file WHERE id = OLD.id; END;
CREATE TABLE object_data ( object_store_id INTEGER NOT NULL, key BLOB NOT NULL, index_data_values BLOB DEFAULT NULL, file_ids TEXT, data BLOB NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (object_store_id, key), FOREIGN KEY (object_store_id) REFERENCES object_store(id) ) WITHOUT ROWID;
CREATE TRIGGER object_data_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON object_data WHEN NEW.file_ids IS NOT NULL BEGIN SELECT update_refcount(NULL, NEW.file_ids);END;
CREATE TRIGGER object_data_update_trigger AFTER UPDATE OF file_ids ON object_data WHEN OLD.file_ids IS NOT NULL OR NEW.file_ids IS NOT NULL BEGIN SELECT update_refcount(OLD.file_ids, NEW.file_ids);END;
CREATE TRIGGER object_data_delete_trigger AFTER DELETE ON object_data WHEN OLD.file_ids IS NOT NULL BEGIN SELECT update_refcount(OLD.file_ids, NULL);END;
CREATE TABLE object_store_index ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, object_store_id INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, key_path TEXT NOT NULL, unique_index INTEGER NOT NULL, multientry INTEGER NOT NULL, locale TEXT, is_auto_locale BOOLEAN, FOREIGN KEY (object_store_id) REFERENCES object_store(id) );
```

Newer 2.6

```
CREATE TABLE database (name TEXT NOT NULL, version INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
CREATE TABLE index_data (index_id INTEGER NOT NULL, value BLOB NOT NULL, object_data_key BLOB NOT NULL, object_data_id INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (index_id,value, object_data_key), FOREIGN KEY (index_id) REFERENCES object_store_index(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (object_data_id) REFERENCES object_data(id) ONDELETE CASCADE);
CREATE INDEX index_data_object_data_id_index ON index_data (object_data_id);
CREATE TABLE object_store (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, auto_increment INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, name TEXT NOT NULL, key_path TEXT, UNIQUE (name));
CREATE TABLE unique_index_data (index_id INTEGER NOT NULL, value BLOB NOT NULL, object_data_key BLOB NOT NULL, object_data_id INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (index_id, value, object_data_key), UNIQUE (index_id, value), FOREIGN KEY (index_id) REFERENCES object_store_index(id) ON DELETE CASCADE FOREIGN KEY (object_data_id) REFERENCES object_data(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
CREATE INDEX unique_index_data_object_data_id_index ON unique_index_data (object_data_id);
CREATE TABLE file (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, refcount INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE TRIGGER file_update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON file FOR EACH ROW WHEN NEW.refcount = 0 BEGIN DELETE FROM file WHERE id = OLD.id; END;
CREATE TABLE object_data (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, object_store_id INTEGER NOT NULL, key_value BLOB DEFAULT NULL, file_ids TEXT, data BLOB NOT NULL, UNIQUE (object_store_id, key_value), FOREIGN KEY (object_store_id) REFERENCES object_store(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
CREATE TRIGGER object_data_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON object_data FOR EACH ROW WHEN NEW.file_ids IS NOT NULL BEGIN SELECT update_refcount(NULL, NEW.file_ids); END;
CREATE TRIGGER object_data_update_trigger AFTER UPDATE OF file_ids ON object_data FOR EACH ROW WHEN OLD.file_ids IS NOT NULL OR NEW.file_ids IS NOT NULL BEGIN SELECT update_refcount(OLD.file_ids, NEW.file_ids); END;
CREATE TRIGGER object_data_delete_trigger AFTER DELETE ON object_data FOR EACH ROW WHEN OLD.file_ids IS NOT NULL BEGIN SELECT update_refcount(OLD.file_ids, NULL); END;
CREATE TABLE object_store_index (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, object_store_id INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, key_path TEXT NOT NULL, unique_index INTEGER NOTNULL, multientry INTEGER NOT NULL, UNIQUE (object_store_id, name), FOREIGN KEY (object_store_id) REFERENCES object_store(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

I have been unable to find a script written by mozilla that addresses this. But I suspect you could trick firefox into repairing this issue for you-- downgrade Firefox insert old database then upgrade firefox. Allow upgrade script to rewrite the database.

Unfortunately these changes look more complex than a simple adding/columns so I doubt you could safely just change or upgrade the existing database. So unless someone at Mozilla left a script lying around I believe there is no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I met this error with Firefox 63, end of 2018.

```
IndexedDB: UnknownError: The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other error code. (error code 0)
```

It comes from many updates over the same user profile.

*localStorage* panel from the debugger was empty, whith keys still accessible.

[devdocs](https://devdocs.io) refused to install offline, with an error indexedDB.

**Solution**: [This mozilla page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) and click the **refresh Firefox** button.

Comment: This will delete all existing IndexedDb data.